# Decrease the space complexity of finding certain letters in String in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, count, space-complexity

**Problem**

I have a problem that finding certain letters in a given String cost too much memory which caused a *"Memory Limit Exceeded"*. I am wondering the reason of it. The question and my codes are below.

**Question**

- describe: Find the number of times the vowels a, e, i, o, u appear in a string.
- Enter: Enter a line of string, the string length is less than 80 characters. So the characters are all lowercase letters.
- Output: Output a line, and output the number of times a, e, i, o, u appear in the input string in sequence, and the integers are separated by spaces.

**Codes**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[] count = new int[5];  // refers to 'a' 'e' 'i' 'o' 'u'
        Scanner buf = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = buf.nextLine();
        buf.close();
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            switch(input.charAt(i)) {
                case 'a': 
                    ++count[0];
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    ++count[1];
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    ++count[2];
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    ++count[3];
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    ++count[4];
                    break;
            }
        }
        for(int item: count) {
            System.out.print(item);
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What parameters are you starting the jvm with?

Comment: What is giving you the "Memory Limit Exceeded" message? Is it an online testing website?

Comment: @tgdavies, a line of string

Comment: @k314159, yes, which indicates that there are better algorithms.

Comment: Can you try with `++(count[0])` or `count[0] =+ 1` ?

Comment: @StéphaneMillien, I just tried it and the result is still MLE.

Comment: I don't think you are using much memory at all. Maybe try not creating a string at all, but just read System.in directly, character by character (without using Scanner).

Comment: @k314159, Thanks so much! As you said, I just deleted the String variable in the middle and passed the problem successfully. I changed the input codes to ```int temp = System.in.read();``` , and change the condition to exit the loop to ```temp == '\n'```.

Comment: btw you shouldn't close System.in. The convention is that any method only closes a resource if it had opened it in the first place.

Comment: @k314159, well, I got it.

Comment: If you manage to solve your problem, then do not edit to solution into your *question*, but instead post it as an *answer* and accept it after the timeout.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, You're right, I've moved the position of the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary

Deleted the call of the `Scanner` class and read characters one by one directly from `System.in`

```java
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        int[] count = new int[5];  // a e i o u
        int temp = System.in.read();
        while(temp != '\n') {
            switch(temp) {
                case 'a': // 97
                    ++count[0];
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    ++count[1];
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    ++count[2];
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    ++count[3];
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    ++count[4];
                    break;
            }
            temp = System.in.read();
        }
        // System.in.close();
        for(int item: count) {
            System.out.print(item);
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
    }
}
```